# Python - 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable?

Tags: python, slice, nonetype

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
 
url = "https://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/computer"

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
results = soup.find_all("a")

for results in results:
    if results.get("href") [:5] == "https":
        print(results.get("href"))
```

This code returns the following error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I have tried putting the [:5] inside of the () which stops the error but doesn't output the hyperlinks. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: `for results in results` Don't use the same variable name for the list and the current list item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always check the return value of a function call.

```
all_results = soup.find_all("a")

for results in all_results:
    result = results.get("href")
    if result is None:
        pass # put a breakpoint here to see all the results which do not contain a "href" tag
    elif result.startswith("https"):
        print(result)
```